# Conversão de valores em flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Preciso pegar um valor que vem de um campo como `text`. Porém, esse campo só recebe números.

Campo do texto:

```
Container(
              child: CupertinoTextField(
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                placeholder: 'Digite um numero',
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 1.0,
                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                maxLines: null,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: controllerTextnum,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17.0, 30.0, 25.0, 1.0),
            ),
```

Botão:

```
 Container(
              child: CupertinoButton(
                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                child: Text("Mostrar número digitado",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                onPressed: (){
                  alertNum(context);
                },
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17.0, 30.0, 25.0, 1.0),
            ),
```

Alert que mostra o que foi digitado no campo.

```
void alertNum (BuildContext context){
  var alert = CupertinoAlertDialog(
    title: Text("O NúMERO Digitado foi:"),
    content: Text(controllerTextnum.text),
    actions: <Widget>[
      CupertinoDialogAction(
        child: Text("Fechar"),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
       
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
  showDialog(context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context){
    return alert;
  }
  );
}
```

Gostaria de pegar esse valor que vem do `CupertinoTextField` e por exemplo multiplicar por 2.

Tinha feito uma função que "jogava" ele em uma variavel dynamic, porém, não deu certo.

Comment: Isso e algo bem simples, voce tem os metodos de conversao, [int.parse(string)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html) e [double.parse(string)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html) e tudo isso esta na doc, se tu por no google flutter converterto to int ou to double, vai aparecer varios post. Voces tem que pesquisar mais antes de perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html):

```
double novoValor = double.parse(controllerTextnum.text);
```

Como dito na documentação, ele jogará uma exceção caso a string fornecida não seja válida como double. Para preparar-se para esse tipo de situação, envolva o comando em um bloco `try / catch`, ou use a seguinte notação:

```
double.tryParse(controllerTextnum.text) ?? (ValorASerEscolhidoCasoFalhaNoParse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa pergunta está mais relacionada a Dart do que Flutter.

Mas você pode utilizar os métodos [parse](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/num/parse.html) e [tryParse](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/num/tryParse.html), presentes no `num`, `int` e `double`. Que convertem uma `String` em um valor numérico.

Exemplo:

```dart
void main() {
  String text = '42';
  String text2 = '42.5';

  //int numero = int.parse(text2); //Erro
  int intTryParse = int.tryParse(text2);
  print('Se deu erro no parse, retorna null: $intTryParse');

  int intParse = int.parse(text);
  print('Valor $intParse, x2: ${intParse * 2}');

  double doubleParse = double.parse(text2);
  print('Valor $doubleParse, x2: ${doubleParse * 2}');

  num numParse = num.parse(text2);
  print('Valor $numParse, x2: ${numParse * 2}');
}
```

Teste aqui no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ab2123db78b02fe0e6366dfc16190ebfhttps://).

Note que caso você tente converter um double em int utilizando apenas o `parse`, será disparado um erro, já com o `tryParse` não é disparado o erro, e sim retornado um `null`.