# Pegar valor do TextFormField em double

Tags: flutter, dart

Como posso pegar o valor de um TextFormField em double? Já criei um TextEditingController,

```
var controller = new TextEditingController();
```

mas o controller.text vem em string e não consigo passá-lo para double.

Comment: Pergunta duplicada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422164/convers%c3%a3o-de-valores-flutter/422171#422171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para receber :

```
controller.text = valor.toStringAsFixed(2); //para retornar com duas casas; 
controller.text = valor.toStringAsFixed(2).replaceAll('.', ','); //se quiser converter o ponto em virgula, padrao pt-br
```

para converter em double:

```
valor = double.tryParse(controller.text) + 0.00;// para nao pegar o valor em tipo dynamic
```

Answer (score -2):

Melhor forma que já encontrei foi:

```
final parsedValue = num.parse(controller.text).toDouble();
```

Answer (score -2):

Para converter a string em um double, você pode usar o método parseDouble() da classe double.

```
var controller = new TextEditingController();
double dValue = double.parse(controller.text);
```

Este código irá retornar o valor do TextFormField como um double, mesmo que o valor original seja uma string.